# only use the ratio test to evalutae $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(\frac{n\pi}{9})}{n!}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

I know that the series is convergent,  proven by the comparison, but the question is asking prove that using the ratio test. When I tried to evaluate the limit $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\left|\frac{\frac{\cos(\frac{n\pi+\pi}{9})}{(n+1)!}}{\frac{\cos(\frac{n\pi}{9})}{n!}}\right|$$ I got stuck at this step $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\left|\frac{\cos(\frac{n\pi+\pi}{9})}{(n+1)\cos(\frac{n\pi}{9})}\right|$$ and I don't know what to do next. How can I continue after this step?

Comment: Hint: the sequence $\{\cos \frac{n\pi}9\}$ has a global minimum.

Comment: Also your title says “evaluate” but that’s not what you’re doing, you’re assessing convergence. The *evaluation* is:$$e^{\cos(\pi/9)}\cos(\sin(\pi/9))-1$$

Comment: Also! $|\cos|<=1$! Do you know that $\sum 1/n!$ converges?

Comment: The task is a torture. The best way win my opinion is  to apply the comparison test as proposed by @FShrike and then  the ratio test.

Answer (score 1):

Use $\cos\left(A+B\right)=\cos A\cos B-\sin A\sin B$ 
$\cos\left(\dfrac{n{\pi}}{9}+\dfrac{{\pi}}{9}\right) = \cos\left(\dfrac{{\pi}}{9}\right)\cos\left(\dfrac{{\pi}n}{9}\right)-\sin\left(\dfrac{{\pi}}{9}\right)\sin\left(\dfrac{{\pi}n}{9}\right)$

So you get,

$$\frac{\cos\left(\frac{{\pi}}{9}\right)}{n+1}-\frac{\sin\left(\frac{{\pi}}{9}\right)\tan\left(\frac{{\pi}n}{9}\right)}{n+1}$$

Now first term is tending to zero as denominator is  very large,
And in second term only $tan(\frac{n\pi}{9})$ can create problem if it tends to infinity (at $\frac{(2n+1)\pi}{2}$) but that cannot happen because you have nine in denominator( which is not multiple of 2)